# Can I allow inbound traffic from internet to a private api gateway in a private aws vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, private, vpc

In aws, I have a private api gateway in my vpc. I want to allow one specific public ip to be allowed to send request to this private api while blocking all other public IP.

How do I achieve this? If I allow the security group and nacl for this one ip, could that ip able to invoke the api? Or would creating a proxy for the IP/ domain work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private API means not accessible from internet. So you can't enable any pubic IP to access it.

You have to develop some proxy for that. Probably the easiest would be a lambda function. So instead of directly calling the API, you use call **lambda function** which in turns calls the private api.